# Add padding to ID link but not show padding

Tags: html, css

I have table of contents on my page that links to IDs on the page, but I have sticky header that overlays some of the ID content when you click on the ID, I would need to add padding to the ID to push the content down pass the sticky nav but if I do that there will be to much space so how can I have the ID link stop the page about 50px or 100px above the ID content?

If you visit my page http://stormable.com/heroes/kerrigan/#abilities you'll see that the navigation is covering the very top part of the #abilities div.

```
<ul>
<li>#abilities</li>
<li>#talents</li>
</ul>

<div id="abilities">
Content
</div>

<div id="talents">
Content
</div>
```

So when you click on abilities it will take you to the very top of the abilities id, I know i can just add padding to the the top of abilities but I don't want to as it will push that to far away from the other content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into javascript for this kind of problems.

But here is a solution:

```
#abilities{
    padding: 50px 0 0;
    margin: -50px 0 0;
}
```

It will do the job. (do the same for all sections)

Comment: Thank you, that works very well. Is there any reason I would be better off using javascript since this does what is needed?

Comment: Not really just personal preference. I just don't like using negative margins. But with js you will be able to animate the scroll, making it look more smooth than to snap it to the section instantly.

Comment: I actually have a JS that does the animated scroll although I'm sure it would better to just combine it but I'm not good enough with JS to do that right now.

Comment: Then this will do you the job. For better response i might consider adding the same class for those section and apply this style to that class instead of apply it to each one.